# There can be nothing with zero mass

Tags: special-relativity

Zero mass has no meaning and is an outcome of 2nd postulate of STR .The STR can be developed without this postulate and thus the postulate is redundant besides being contradictory to 1st postulate.The "c" appearing in STR is the limiting highest speed which can never be achieved by any material particle by any means.Instead of accepting the occult Zero mass to photon we should design experiments to:

1- establish the mechanism by which the photons are accelerated close to the limiting speed

2- determine the rest mass of photon
The absurdity of assigning Zero mass to photon is apparent through following cases:

1- Thought experiment of inelastic collision of electron and photon

2- Bending of the trajectory of photons due to gravitational pull by massive bodies

Comment: Most of this is senseless.  But, more importantly, what's your question?

Comment: Gravitational pull is independent of mass, so gravitational trajectories can't possibly say anything about a particle's mass. Something with zero mass gets pulled just as much as something with a mass of one million tons, and this is a basic point of Newtonian gravity and GR. All you've demonstrated at best is that photon-electron collisions cannot be modeled as inelastic classical collisions between rigid bodies. Since we're dealing with both relativity and quantum mechanics, this should be a fairly obvious dead end.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a question.

> Zero mass has no meaning

Zero mass has meaning and is perfectly well defined. Zero mass photons do have energy and momentum. And if trapped in a box add to the perceived mass of the box by E/c^2 where E is their energy.

Their mass has been measured to be

$$
<1×10^{−18} \frac{eV}{c^2}
$$

> Bending of the trajectory of photons due to gravitational pull by massive bodies

This does not disagree with zero mass, and in fact zero mass photons cause gravity effects themselves since they have energy and gravity is a result of energy.